# Can't view files in Xcode after selecting in project navigator

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm select a file in the project navigator (it is there, it is not red or missing) and Xcode simply does not open the file.

https://twitter.com/zachshakked/status/1453033845931003907 (I added a screen recording here).

I just updated to Xcode 13.1

Answer (score 0):

Lol. My console was covering the entire screen. Cmd+Shift+Y fixed it.